# Can't run emacs as daemon

Tags: emacs

Trying to run

```
>emacs --daemon
```

in a shell produces

```
Warning: due to a long standing Gtk+ bug
http://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85715
Emacs might crash when run in daemon mode and the X11 connection is unexpectedly lost.
Using an Emacs configured with --with-x-toolkit=lucid does not have this problem.
Loading /home/me/.emacs.d/customizations/navigation.el (source)...
Loading /home/me/.emacs.d/.recentf...
Loading /home/me/.emacs.d/.recentf...done
Cleaning up the recentf list...
Loading /home/me/.emacs.d/customizations/navigation.el (source)...done
Loading /home/me/.emacs.d/customizations/ui.el (source)...

Backtrace:
emacs[0x505e79]
emacs[0x4ed4cc]
emacs[0x504b2e]
emacs[0x504ce3]
emacs[0x504d6f]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xfc90)[0x7f1ba0acac90]
emacs[0x44cd4e]
emacs[0x471ad2]
emacs[0x55f137]
emacs[0x5939c3]
emacs[0x55ef53]
emacs[0x55f3fa]
emacs[0x566333]
emacs[0x566592]
emacs[0x55f137]
emacs[0x5939c3]
emacs[0x55ef53]
emacs[0x5939c3]
emacs[0x55ef53]
emacs[0x5939c3]
emacs[0x55ef53]
emacs[0x5939c3]
emacs[0x55ef53]
emacs[0x5939c3]
emacs[0x560148]
emacs[0x55e3e6]
emacs[0x58219a]
emacs[0x5824a9]
emacs[0x55f0fb]
emacs[0x5939c3]
emacs[0x55eb92]
emacs[0x55ef53]
emacs[0x55f309]
emacs[0x582a73]
emacs[0x55e607]
emacs[0x58219a]
emacs[0x5824a9]
emacs[0x55f0fb]
emacs[0x5939c3]
emacs[0x55eb92]
emacs[0x55ef53]
...
Error: server did not start correctly
```

Similar happens when I go with

```
> emacsclient -c -a ""
```

Starting emacs the normal way, I can do

```
M-x (server-start)
```

but I don't think it's actually working, because running

```
(defun --running-as-server ()
    "Returns true if `server-start' has been called."
  (condition-case nil
      (and (boundp 'server-process)
           (memq (process-status server-process)
                 '(connect listen open run)))
    (error)))
```

in ielm gives only

```
(listen open run)
```

back instead of T or nil, and running

```
ELISP> (daemonp)
```

gives back nil. My version of Emacs is GNU Emacs 25.0.50.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.12.2) on Ubuntu 14.10. How can I get Emacs to run as a server/daemon?

Comment: Did you build Emacs yourself or use a package? If a package, from the official repositories, or from a PPA or other third-party source?

Comment: from a PPA. I think it was this one: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-elisp/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: Sure, the same PPA here, and the same problem. Looks like a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I run emacs on Slackware 14.2 in daemon mode.  My only issue was I was tired of seeing the warning.  Other than that, the server ran fine for my purposes.  What I did to get rid of the warning was to download the latest version of emacs from their official site
(emacs 26.1), removed the emacs package that came with my Slackware version, then unpacked and compiled the new version:

sudo tar -xvf emacs-26.1.tar.xz

./configure --with-x-toolkit=lucid

make

sudo make install

It's been running fine, no problems and no warning when the server starts.
You might want to give that a try.  The GNU Project site here http://mirror.keystealth.org/gnu/emacs/ has the latest versions in .tar.gz format as well if you prefer

Answer (score -2):

I was encountering this same error and was able to resolve it by removing my .emacs.d directory.

```
rm -fr ~/.emacs.d
```

Comment: This's like throwing the baby out with the bathwater